# AVAudioPlayer doesn't play audio in iPhone 5 when locked

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Using AVAudioPlayer I'm trying to play sounds while the iphone player is playing. Also when device is locked.
The thing is, that in iPhone 4s ios 7 - works fine. 
But on iPhone 5 with 6 and 7 ios nothing happens.

In the `-Info.plist` in `Required background modes` I wrote

`App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay`

in `Player.h` implemented:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *notificationPlayer;
```

`<AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioSessionDelegate>` with 
`#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` included

Also in `Player.m`

```
//this is called on viewDidLoad
-(void) prepareSound{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
}
//overriden function
- (void)playAudio:(NSString *)path{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
     setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient
     withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers
     error: nil];

    NSError *error;
    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    self.notificationPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error];
    self.notificationPlayer.delegate = self;
    [self.notificationPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.notificationPlayer setVolume:1.0];
    [self.notificationPlayer play];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    [player stop]; 
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:0 error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient
                                     withOptions: 0
                                           error: nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES withOptions: 0 error:nil];
}
//Call from here
-(void) customMethod{
    [self playAudio:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3" ofType:@"wav"]];
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Are you sure you've added that row in the `info.plist` for the right project target and not the `test` target? I had made that mistake and it took around 2.5 days to figure it out! I thought everything is correct and it's not working!

Comment: @Neeku, thanks for your reply! Yes, I added the row to the project target, not to the test target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use the following code

```
- (void)playAudio:(NSString *)path {
NSError *error;
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

self.notificationPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error];
self.notificationPlayer.delegate = self;

AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *errorSession = nil;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:NO error:&errorSession];

[self.notificationPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.notificationPlayer setVolume:1.0];
[self.notificationPlayer play];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
NSLog(@"Should play music");
}

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
[player stop];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withFlags:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another Really important thing to note while playing sounds in background is whether or not you have permission to the file.  If you are playing a bundle file, you have permission, and presumably some file streamed from the internet, but if you've downloaded media into the documents directory, then you must set permissions appropriately, especially if your application natively locks files.

This tends to match with what many people see as a symptom where the file will continue to play for a couple of seconds, 5-15, then stop.  If you're listening for the finished method, you'll see an error flag.  Why: AVAudioPlayer won't load the entirety of your audio file into memory when you first play it.
Example:

```
  NSURL url = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];

  NSError *error = nil;
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:@{NSFileProtectionKey :
  NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication} ofItemAtPath:[url path] error:&error];
```

Your options are as follows:

```
  NSFileProtectionComplete;
  NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen;
  NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication;
  NSFileProtectionNone;
```

Comment: Thank you for these details