# how to keep an avaudioplayer playing in device(iPhone) locked condition?

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer in my application.my problem is, it is not playing when the device gets locked.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570211/avaudioplayer-doesnt-play-audio-in-iphone-5-when-locked

Comment: thanks ! it'll help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code:

```
- (void)playAudio:(NSString *)path {
NSError *error;
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

self.notificationPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error];
self.notificationPlayer.delegate = self;

AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *errorSession = nil;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:NO error:&errorSession];

[self.notificationPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.notificationPlayer setVolume:1.0];
[self.notificationPlayer play];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
NSLog(@"Should play music");
}

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
[player stop];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withFlags:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
}
```

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570211/avaudioplayer-doesnt-play-audio-in-iphone-5-when-locked)

Hope this code useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps in the image below. It should work.

[image]